# Using reftex-citation with yasnippet

Tags: emacs, auctex

I'm trying to make a yasnippet with [this function](https://github.com/madsdk/yasnippets-latex/blob/master/cite.yasnippet)

```
\cite{${1:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-citation nil 'dont-insert))}}$0
```

work but when I run it I get

> [yas] elisp error!

The strange thing is that I have equivalent snippets but with `reftex-reference` instead of `reftex-citation` that runs fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your snippet.  The first argument, not the second, of `reftex-citation` is `NO-INSERT`. So I think it should be:

```
\cite{${1:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-citation 'dont-insert))}}$0
```

Regardless, either way works for me.  When I was testing it, I got an error

```
"No valid bibliography in this document, and no default available"
```

so that might be your problem.  Can you run `reftex-citation` via <kbd>C-c [</kbd> in the document?

Comment: I removed `nil` from the expression as you suggested and it works perfectly. Thanks for helping me with my Emacs problems!